# How can I use a transaction hash from Hashscan in a JSON-RPC query, on Hedera?

Tags: rpc, hedera-hashgraph, hedera

I'm looking at a transaction on Hashscan

Its transaction hash is:
`0x89eb7e219df6f8b3b3406c8a3698d5b484a4945059af643861c878e41ffc161b2589cc82ff40b4392ceb53856c5252c1`
... which does not work with the `eth_getTransactionByHash` RPC:

```bash
TXHASH=0x89eb7e219df6f8b3b3406c8a3698d5b484a4945059af643861c878e41ffc161b2589cc82ff40b4392ceb53856c5252c1

curl -s -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"2","method":"eth_getTransactionByHash","params":["'"${TXHASH}"'"]}' \
    http://localhost:7546 | jq
```

The error is:

```json
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": "2",
    "error": {
        "code": -32602,
        "name": "Invalid parameter",
        "message": "[Request ID: 5fda4d4a-3160-4f8f-8ed3-51ad64dada46] Invalid parameter 0: Expected 0x prefixed string representing the hash (32 bytes) of a transaction, value: 0x89eb7e219df6f8b3b3406c8a3698d5b484a4945059af643861c878e41ffc161b2589cc82ff40b4392ceb53856c5252c1"
}
```

How can I get a transaction hash that can be used in RPCs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

​

- In Hedera, transaction hashes are 48 bytes, which are represented as 96 hexits

  - 96 hexadecimal digits
  - 98 characters total length when represented as a string, due to the `0x` prefix
- In the EVM, transaction hashes are 32 bytes, which are represented as 64 hexits

  - 64 hexadecimal digits
  - 66 characters total length when represented as a string, due to the `0x` prefix
    ​
    You need to convert from the Hedera transaction hash format
    to the EVM transaction hash format,
    in order to use it in RPC endpoints.
    ​
    To do so, simply truncate to the required length.
    You can do this in the shell with `TXHASHEVM=${TXHASH:0:66}`,
    and then using `TXHASHEVM` as the 1st parameter of
    the `eth_getTransactionByHash` RPC request.
    ​

---

**Example**
​
Request:
​

```bash
TXHASH=0x89eb7e219df6f8b3b3406c8a3698d5b484a4945059af643861c878e41ffc161b2589cc82ff40b4392ceb53856c5252c1
​
TXHASHEVM=${TXHASH:0:66}
​
curl -s -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"2","method":"eth_getTransactionByHash","params":["'"${TXHASHEVM}"'"]}' \
    http://localhost:7546 | jq ".result"
```

​
Response:
​

```json
{
  "blockHash": "0x84e4e82415f707eeb24fa9514500aaae55dbeb43d63a4e0e4bbd827ada9dcdd5",
  "blockNumber": "0x452953",
  "chainId": null,
  "from": "0x3633d26fb458e6723ac9f8c2d5659b04eb666283",
  "gas": "0xea60",
  "gasPrice": null,
  "hash": "0x89eb7e219df6f8b3b3406c8a3698d5b484a4945059af643861c878e41ffc161b",
  "input": "0x368b87720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b6e6577206d657373616765000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "maxPriorityFeePerGas": null,
  "maxFeePerGas": null,
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "r": null,
  "s": null,
  "to": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000469c13",
  "transactionIndex": "0x24",
  "type": null,
  "v": "0x0",
  "value": "0x0"
}
```